# Yii appending new route to the exisitng route in url with Yii-bootstrap but working fine with CMenu

Tags: url, yii, url-routing

am actually having some issue with url routing while using TbMenu widget,i am using the format of /moduleId/ControllerId/ActionId in accessing module Controllers,here is an example

```
<?php  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
'type'=>'inverse', // null or 'inverse'
'brand'=>'mysite',
'brandUrl'=>'#',
'collapse'=>true, // requires bootstrap-responsive.css
'items'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home','url'=>array('/site/index'), 'active'=>true),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page')),
            array('label'=>'Contact us','url'=>array('/site/contact')),
        ),
    ),
    '<form class="navbar-search pull-left" action=""><input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search"></form>',
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Sign in', 'url'=>'/user/auth','visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            '---',
           [b] array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>'/user/user','visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest, 'items'=>array([/b]
                [b]array('label'=>'Settings', 'url'=>'user/user/index'),[/b]
                [b]array('label'=>'Logout', 'url'=>'user/user/logout')[/b],

            )),
        ),
    ),
),
```

he three last line are the ones that are causing problem,when i try to access those links after clicking on home,page,contact us(using the Site controller actions that are auto-generated by the Yii) the route is appended to the existing url in stead of creating a new url to the module,for example if am on home page(after clicking home it has this as url **localhost/mysite/index.php/site/index)**it gives me this url localhost/mysite/index.php/site/index/user/user/index,if i go the same link again with this as url it gives me **localhost/mysite/index/user/user/index/user/user/index** if i click again it add another one again and again..but the strange in all is that it works fine with CMenu,here is snippet of CMenu that works fine,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
                    'items'=>array(
                            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('//user/auth'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('//user/user/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                            array('label'=>'My profile ', 'url'=>array('/user/user/'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                    ),
            )); ?>
```

i am assuming that it might be caused by the fact that those links are submenu but i am not sure since the first in those links is not submenu and has the same problem!thank you again

Comment: try prepending a `/` before the module name ie like `array('label'=>'Settings', 'url'=>'/user/user/index')`

Comment: i did it and it all give the same thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TbMenu component is using CHtml::link to display the links...

```
CHtml::link(label, url, options)
```

CHtml::link  method has one check

```
if url is an array ... then use controller->createUrl(...) method
if url is a string ... then just return that string.
```

So, I think, @dInGd0nG suggestion would work.
if not then you should be using array ...something like ( don't forget to prefix / )

```
array('label'=>'Settings', 'url'=> array('/user/user/index') ),
array('label'=>'Logout', 'url'=> array('/user/user/logout') )
```

Comment: SuveRa..you were right..i was missing the array..it really worked fine using your suggestion.thanks a lot!